# Setting the LoadedBehaviour and UnloadedBehaviour of MediaElement WPF Application(C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I am playing a video in a `MediaElement` in a WPF application. However when I am programatically invoking  the `Play()` , `Pause()` or `Stop()` I get an error message saying:

> Cannot control media unless LoadedBehavior or UnloadedBehavior is set to Manual.

I have no idea about it.

Can someone tell me how can these be set to *`MANUAL`*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In XAML you can set the value to the properties like this:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="player"
              LoadedBehavior="Manual"
              UnloadedBehavior="Stop" ... />
```

Or using code behind:

```
player.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
player.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Stop;
```